# Making a live counter start when an element in array changes?

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a data feed from an API that returns an array of arrays with "name", "call status", and "time" fields:

```
[["alex", "wrap", "1395673193"], ["bill", "call", "1395673370"], ["chelsea", "wait", "1395673363"], ["david", "wait", "1395673374"], ["kirsty", "call", "1395673340"], ["natalie", "wait", "1395673360"], ["rose", "wait", "1395673374"], ["shirley", "wait", "1395673378"], ["stuart", "call", "1395673101"], ["wendy", "call", "1395673352"]]
```

The time is a Uxix time stamp but I don't think I need it for now.

I display them in a view with a jQuery partial refreshing every second:

```
<% @ta.each do |elem| %> 
 <td><%  elem.each_slice(3) do |a,b,c| %></td>
 <td><%=  a %></td>
 <td><%=  b %></td>
 <td><%=  c %></td>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

What I would like to do is display a live counter, like a stopwatch, that resets everytime `b` changes but I can't figure out how to trigger the clock starting.

I have tried adding somthing like the following to my view that is refreshed by jQuery every second:

```
 <td><%  elem.each_slice(3) do |a,b,c| %></td>
 <td><%=  a %></td>
 <td><%=  b %></td>
 <td><%= (b == @timecheck ? "0" : "1" ) %></td>
 <% @timecheck = b %>
<% end %>
```

with the logic being that "1" should appear and then return to "0" on the next iteration, meaning I could use it as a trigger. But this does not work because it holds the value for the previous agent rather than the same agent on the previous loop, if you get me.

I suspect I am doing way too much in the view, and that the logic should be in the controller, but I can move it once it is working. For now it's just a mashup of things I am trying.

I think I might be going about this all wrong, but I'm very new at all this.

Comment: Thanks for the edit the Tin Man. I will do the same on future questions.

Comment: No takers? Im still stuck! But my new plan of attack is creating two hashes for "name" and "status" key-pairs, then save and check against alternate ones using loop counter and odd and evens! Lets see if it will work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days, I finally figured it out! Just incase it helps someone else, here is how i did it. It simply stores the status in opposite arrays on each loop, so it can compare one loop to the other to see if there was a change.

```
count = 0
@changeodd = Hash.new
@changeeven = Hash.new
@time = Hash.new
loop do
  count = count + 1
  a = Agentfeed.get("http://myAPI/ajax.php?token=""#{@token}""&method=agents&action=read")
  b = a["list"]
  @feedarray = []
     b.each do |feed|

     name = feed["name"]
     status = feed["status"]

  if count.odd?
     @changeodd[name] = status
     if @changeeven[name] == status
        @time[name] = @time[name] + 1
     else
    @time[name] = 1
     end
   else
     @changeeven[name] = status
     if @changeodd[name] == status
    @time[name] = @time[name] + 1
     else
    @time[name] = 1
     end
   end


@feed = []
@feed << name << status << @time[name]
@feedarray << @feed

end
```